Tying to read a URL with Ruby and open-uri is giving a 403 error
I have a process that has been running successfully on a Raspberry Pi for years that is now suddently failing.  I am scraping a website so I am passing a URL to open-uri and then parsing it with Nokogiri
page = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(uri), nil, "UTF-8")

I can see in the logs that I am getting a 403 forbidden response and indeed if I run the script manually on the Pi after SSH-ing in, I get the same error.  If I use:
Net::HTTP.get(uri)

I get a page back which contains this:
<span id=\"challenge-error-text\">Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue</span>

and I assume this is what is causing the 403 when I use open-uri.
Why would this have suddenly started happening after years of successfully running and how might I get around it?
The Pi is on my home network and if I run the exact same commands from my laptop (so presenting the exact same external IP) it all works with no issue!  This is part of a Rais project with versions controlled by a Gemfile so both the Pi and my laptop are using the same versions of all the libraries.
I tried with Curl on my laptop and initially got the page with the error but when I then passed a user agent string through with it, I got the page I wanted but this is not working on the Pi - the same Curl string with the same user agent string is still giving me the error page.
I installed the text browser lynx on the Pi and went to the same URL I am getting the error from and it connected fine and showed me the page.
I have updated the Pi and rebooted.  It is running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1119-raspi aarch64)

check all the headers you are sending in the OK cases.

It could be that the site you are crawling is doing some bot detection to prevent others from crawling it. Their detection algorithm is being triggered, very likely by an HTTP header, that the code sends (or not sends) when running on the RaspberryPi compared to what your laptop sends from the same network.

Interesting. I wonder what that could be as I’m running the exact same rake task with the exact same inputs on my laptop where it works as I am on the Pi where it doesn’t so I wonder what headers could be getting added/omited.

"challenge-error-text" appears to be associated with CloudFlare. CloudFlare implements what it calls "Bot Management" as a way to mitigate scraping and other bots. It appears that some libraries have been created to try and circumvent these defensive techniques although your choices for ruby seem limited.

Ah, OK, could be it. Strange that the exact same process using the exact same code does not get flagged if I run it on my laptop which would expose the exact same IP address as the Pi but I’ll see if I can monitor the headers to check for differences
